# WPF DatePicker Validation When Text Entered In Correct Date Format

Tags: wpf

I am having trouble firing a validation once the user enters text to the DatePicker (not when selecting the date through the DatePicker). I want it to fire the validation only when the text is in a format of a date, such as "MM/dd/yyyy", but when using the Text property and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, it will fire validation for every time a text is entered. I also have set my binding SomeDate to a DateTime. Is there a way to do this without changing my binding to a string?

```
<DatePicker x:Name = "date" 
        Text = "{Binding SomeDate, Mode=TwoWay,    
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

I also tried using SelectedDate property instead of Text, but this only triggers the validation when you press enter for the text-entered date or when you select the date through the DatePicker UI. I understand why all of this is happening, but cannot think of a solution.

I also tried Text property and UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, but looking at the events that can be triggered, they don't seem to be helpful. I tried using PreviewTextInput but that doesn't work either because there is no way to get new text entered. There is also no TextChanged event property for DatePicker.

```
<DatePicker x:Name = "date" PreviewTextInput = "onInput"
        Text = "{Binding SomeDate, Mode=TwoWay,  
        UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` an option for you?

Comment: How about setting UpdateSourceTrigger to explicit and adding an eventhandler that checks if the entered string complies with your expected format and if this is the case, call UpdateSource() for the datepicker?

Comment: @SajithSageer It's not an option for me.

Comment: @Jan Is there a specific event for datepicker that I can use?

Comment: I'm just guessing now: SelectedDateChanged  might be the one. but you've to test